# LXC bridge with eth0

Tags: lxc

My host eth0 is connected to my office network. I want bridging the LXC container with host's eth0. I have changed lxc.network.link  of the container to eth0, but it prevents the container to be launched.

Answer (score 1):

i'm using this config and works great.

```
# cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
# cat /var/lib/lxc/<CONTAINER NAME>/config
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.link = br0
```